# upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, backup

I'm Planning to upgrade to 14.04 . so what are the precautions i need to do . and is there a way to go back if things goes bad . i would appreciate if some one tells me a check list to follow to do this upgrade successfully

Comment: No questions about development versions of Ubuntu are allowed here. Your question will become acceptable after the official release of 14.04.

Comment: @ToDo well, I am not so sure. He is asking about the final version of 14.04, not how to upgrade to a beta.

Comment: @Rmano that's right . As it will be released in about two weeks so I want to know the best scenario to upgrade to 14.04 when it's released

Comment: I'll close this for now - we'll update the master question closer to the release date.

Comment: i'm not sure why 10 reputations points should be deduced for this question . can you tell me